# I want to render HTML as well as plain text in the email

Tags: python, email, smtp, mime

I am getting email with attachment of html. I am expecting that my email has html and plain text both rendered without any attachment

```
# Create the MIME multipart message
msg = MIMEMultipart("mixed")


plain_text = "This is the plain text version of the email."
plain_part = MIMEText(plain_text, 'plain')
msg.attach(plain_part)

html_text = """
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <p>This is the <b>HTML</b> version of the email.</p>
</body>
</html>
"""
html_part = MIMEText(html_text, 'html')
msg.attach(html_part)


msg['From'] = sender_email
msg['To'] = receiver_email
msg['Subject'] = "subject"


with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
    server.starttls()
    server.login(smtp_username, smtp_password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receive`your text`r_email, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: What if you change the `MIMEMultipart` to "alternative"?

Comment: if I am using MIMEMultipart("alternative") , still that doesnt works

Comment: What behavior are you seeing then?  Email clients do not render both the text and HTML parts of the message simultaneously - they show one or the other.  The standard says to show the last part (in your case the HTML) first and so you're likely to only see the HTML.

Comment: is there a way to show both

Comment: There isn't a standard way of doing that and have it work on all email clients.  The "mixed" type in theory should allow it but I've not seen clients that do that.  I've not heard of a use case where both needed to be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

---

**Changes made:**
Changed **MIMEMultipart("mixed")** to **MIMEMultipart("alternative")** since you want to provide alternative versions of the content (plain text and HTML), not mix them.
Removed the unnecessary backticks from the **server.sendmail()** call.
This corrected code should send an email with both HTML and plain text content without any attachments. Just make sure to replace the placeholder values with your actual email sending configuration.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Your email sending configuration
smtp_server = "your_smtp_server"
smtp_port = 587
smtp_username = "your_username"
smtp_password = "your_password"
sender_email = "sender@example.com"
receiver_email = "receiver@example.com"

# Create the MIME multipart message
msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")  # Use "alternative" instead of "mixed"

plain_text = "This is the plain text version of the email."
plain_part = MIMEText(plain_text, 'plain')
msg.attach(plain_part)

html_text = """
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <p>This is the <b>HTML</b> version of the email.</p>
</body>
</html>
"""
html_part = MIMEText(html_text, 'html')
msg.attach(html_part)

msg['From'] = sender_email
msg['To'] = receiver_email
msg['Subject'] = "subject"

# Use the SMTP_SSL() context manager for better security
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
    server.login(smtp_username, smtp_password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, msg.as_string())
```

For STARTTLS:

```
with smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
    server.starttls()
    server.login(smtp_username, smtp_password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, msg.as_string())
```

For SMTPS (SMTP over SSL):

```
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
    server.login(smtp_username, smtp_password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, msg.as_string())
```

Comment: self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1131)

Comment: Check SMTP Server and Port: Make sure you are using the correct SMTP server address and port. Different servers might use different SSL/TLS configurations. Verify that the server and port combination you're using is appropriate for your email provider.

Use the Correct SMTP Protocol: Depending on your email provider's settings, you might need to use either STARTTLS or SMTPS (SMTP over SSL). Ensure that you are using the correct protocol. Here's how you can adjust the code accordingly:

Comment: You should really look at the comments - the poster isn't having a problem sending email and tried `alternative`.  For some reason they want to display the HTML and plain text at the same time.